# Why Alpha-animation is reset?

Tags: java, android, listview, animation

I have xml for alpha-hide animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.15"
        android:duration="200" />
</set>
```

I have a code for launch this animation when click on the `floating action button`:

```
addDiaryMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              listview.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Diarys.this, R.anim.alpha_hide));
            }
        });
```

And that's what happens. When you click on the button, the animation starts, but after a couple of seconds, the `ListView` loses its transparency. And this happens **only if I click on the button immediately after the start of the activity**. If after the start of the activity a couple of seconds pass, then the animation works as it should.

I don't know why it happens. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: just remove attribute android:fillAfter="true" from parent tag and try once

Comment: If I removing it, the Listview does not remain translucent after the animation completes.